# Is it possible to read Color information in ncurses

Tags: c++, terminal, ncurses

is it possible to read the current information about the color at a specific coordinate in an ncurses window using c++?

My aim is to "draw" something like an ASCII-style line over some colored background, without reseting the original background color.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at [attr_get()](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_attr.3x.html)?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this function, but it seems just to return the color, last defined by color_set(). Not for a special (x,y) position.
What I've tried was just to look through documentations and look for suitable functions, but I wasn't successful for now.

Comment: [mvinch(y,x)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inch.3x.html) may do what you want.

Comment: nice, that did the trick. So the final code to extract the color information is:
`short color = (mvinch(x,y) & A_COLOR) >>8;`

thanks heaps.